# Converting column type when converting pandas dataframe to spark dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pandas dataframe whose column data types are all string. I want to convert it to a spark dataframe, and I need to convert its data types using a schema; however, I get the following error. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['1', '2'], 'col2': ['3', '4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
  StructField('col1', IntegerType(), True),
  StructField('col2', IntegerType(), True)
])
sparkDf = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema = schema)
display(sparkDf)
```

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

How can I impose the spark schema on the pandas dataframe when all the pandas column types are string type?
Thanks :)

Comment: try "df['col1'] = df['col1].astype(int)" (and for other cols too

Comment: As @EzerK mentions, you can use `astype` for converting the data types. You can also use a dictionary to cast the data types before converting to spark: `sparkDf = spark.createDataFrame(df.astype({"col1":int,"col2":int}), schema = schema)
`

Comment: If the `schema` is already defined, you can easily `cast` the spark columns afterward using it

Comment: Thanks for you comments guys. I have one problem that is not covered by your comments. one is that there are some columns in the spark schema that are not in the pandas schema. I can compare the list of columns and create empty columns in the pandas dataframe for missing ones, but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to do that. Thanks